# batch robocopy is deleting all of my files

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have the following directory structure:

```
\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test
\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\mycopy.bat
\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup
\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\asdf.txt
\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\a_directory
\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\a_directory\qwer.txt
```

In the event that a key file doesn't exist, I want to copy backup/* into the directory "test." This gets executed from mycopy.bat:

```
if exist "\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\myservice.exe" (
    echo "all is good."
) else (
    robocopy "\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup" "\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test" /MIR /R:1 /W:2
)
```

This gives me the following error and ends up just deleting everything in the "test" directory. I was able to copy everything from my test directory into the backup directory using `robocopy` but I can't seem to get the opposite working.

```
  Started : Sunday, July 15, 2018 3:59:19 AM
   Source : C:\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\
     Dest : C:\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1 /W:2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    C:\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\
        *EXTRA Dir        -1    C:\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\
          *EXTRA File                  0        asdf.txt
        *EXTRA Dir        -1    C:\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\a_directory\
          *EXTRA File                  0        qwer.txt
          *EXTRA File                177        s.bat
            New File                   0        asdf.txt
2018/07/15 03:59:19 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Copying File C:\Users\DorrisPringle\Desktop\test\backup\asdf.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Since the destination also contains the source and you chose to mirror (`/MIR`) source to directory, the `backup` folder is seen as an extra directory (one that exists in the destination only, as there is no `backup\backup` folder), [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) deletes it. Since `robocopy` does not enumerate the whole directory tree prior to copying/moving/deleting, an error is thrown. If you add `/L` (list only), no error arises. Anyway, you said you want to *copy* stuff, simply replace `/MIR` by `/E`; perhaps adding `/XX` might be useful too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/MIR` switch is equivalent to `/E /PURGE`

`/PURGE` instructs `robocopy` to delete everything in the destination (test directory) that is not exist in your source (backup directory) before starting coping files, but since the backup directory itself is in the destination it will be deleted too.

Just replace `/MIR` with `/E` switch